# Uncaught Error: Class 'Timber' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I want to create my own theme using Timber in wordpress. I followed the timber documentation and was successfully able to render home.twig template through index.php.

But now I have a link to another page say donate.php in my home.twig where donate.php has the code to render donate.twig template and

when I try to click on that link  I get the folowing error -
  `Uncaught Error: Class 'Timber' not found in /path/to/donate.php`

index.php

```
$context = array();

 Timber::render('/templates/views/home.twig', $context);
```

donate.php

```
<?php
require('/app/plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
require('/app/plugins/timber-library/vendor/autoload.php');
$context = array();
Timber::render('/templates/views/donate.twig', $context);
```

Please let me know if I am missing any details in the question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you require the auto loader?

Comment: @DarkBee No I did not require the auto loader.. Where should I require it in my code? My donate.php code is only of those 3 lines which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Just require the `loader` right after `<?php` and you should be fine

Comment: @DarkBee, I modified the code (donate.php), added require loader lines. And now I am getting a different error. It says `  Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/app/plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/example.com/current/web/app/themes/jhatkaa-timber-theme/campaigns.php on line 2 ` . I dont understand why I am getting this error when I have the file in correct position.

Comment: `require(__DIR__. '/../../plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');` - Try this one.

Comment: @DarkBee... Thank you for immediate response..." fatal error: require()" has gone... but I still get Timber class not found error - " Class 'Timber' not found in /srv/www/example.com/current/web/app/themes/jhatkaa-timber-theme/campaigns.php on line 9" . Do you think my procedure is wrong ? Basically I called home.twig from index.php ( worked fine ). and I have an anchor tag reffering donate.php in my home.twig  <a href = /path/to/donate.php" >. where donate.php is rendering donate.twig. Please let me know if the procedure is wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: As Timber resides in the namespace `Timber` you need to use `Timber\Timber::render(...)` or place `use Timber\Timber;` at top of the tile